# jQuery placing .each() functions inside a .click() function

Tags: javascript, jquery

The `.each()` functions inside the `.click()` are not running. I do not know how to structure them to make it syntactically correct so jQuery will recognize and run them.

I tried tacking them on before the closing `});` but I either didn't do it right or that isn't how it's done. I tried Googling but other than my topic title I was at a loss for what to search. I did try *jquery function inside function* but that turned out to be a lost cause.

EDIT: I have managed to get the first one to fire properly (`//POST specials`) however, the second one still isn't working. I even tried to put the `extras POST` inside the `.ajax()` of the `specials` and it didn't work.

```
$('.class').find('#button').click(function() {

        //all kinds of variables here

        var dataString = {//variables:variables}
        console.log(dataString);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "classes/reserve.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html)
            {
                //POST specials
                $('#specialscheck input:checked').each(function() {
                    var reservation = $('#reservation').val();
                    var special = parseInt($(this).attr('id'));
                    dataString = {reservation:reservation, special:special};
                    console.log(dataString);
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "classes/insert_specials.php",
                        data: dataString,
                        cache: false,
                        success: function(html)
                        {
                            //$('.unitinfolist').html(html);
                        }
                    }); 
                });

                //POST extras
                $('#extrascheck input:checked').each(function() {
                    var reservation = $('#reservation').val();
                    var extra = parseInt($(this).attr('id'));
                    dataString = {reservation:reservation, extra:extra};
                    console.log(dataString);
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "classes/insert_extras.php",
                        data: dataString,
                        cache: false,
                        success: function(html)
                        {
                            //$('.unitinfolist').html(html);
                        }
                    }); 
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: In a general sense you can put an `.each()` inside any function including a click handler. Are you sure `$('.checkboxes1 input:checked')` is using the correct selector? If no elements match that selector the `.each()` wouldn't do anything. If those elements are created by your initial Ajax call they won't exist yet when the `.each()` statement occurs. You could test how many elements match with `console.log($('.checkboxes2 input:checked').length)`. Perhaps you could show some of your html? (Or provide a demo for us at http://jsfiddle.net.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move the .each up into the `success` function of the jquery post, or set its `async: false`, to follow this pattern.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType,
  async:false
});
```

Comment: I tried what you said and it halfway worked. I have edited my question to reflect my changes.

Comment: Remember to set the async:false too